# Combine two separate buffers into a complex one

Tags: c++

i'm working to a project involving realtime rx and tx trasmission using a Software Defined Radio.

I have to pass the SDR transmission API a Complex Float array buffer to be sent. I'm trying to implement every feature avoid using "for loops" since working each element at a time slow down the code execution, since i need to do many upsampling, FIR filtering and other computing intensive computation. 
Now i am facing a problem.  Suppose i have two separate buffers one representing the real part and the other the imag part of the complex samples buffer i have to pass to the API tx function.
Say real buffer is  RRRRRRRRRRRR while the imag buffer is IIIIIIIIIIII.  The example is for 12 samples but really it could be 2048, 4096 or more ...

```
int size=12 
float *reals,*imags;
reals = new float[size];
image = new float[size];
```

Now i need an output that is defined as

```
complex<float> *cplxOut;
cplxOut = new complex<float>[size];
```

In memory this object is stored as RIRIRIRIRIRIRIRIRIRIRIRI.

build the  cplxOut from the two real and imag buffers is easy using a for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
  (*(cplxOut+i)).real(*(reals+i));
  (*(cplxOut+i)).imag(*(imags+i));
}
```

I wonder if there is a quickest way to do it using direct memory move functions for whole buffers.

I tried to use inline assembly to speed up the task but it has problem in portability on different architectures and is not supported for x64 on Windows side. 
A possibile way could be upsample by two interleaving with zero, shift forward the imag buffer of 1 place and then OR both buffers, but to do upsampling i have to use a for loop as well.. so no way.

Do you have any suggestion ?  I need the fastest way to do it.

Tnx, Fabio

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but we're doing the same kind of thing.  If you're on an x86 box have you looked at using IPP? https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference  Also, don't use `complex<>`  Create a structure `{ float re; float im; }` and you won't have this problem.  It will be stored properly RIRIRIRI...

Comment: If the buffers are large it may be worth trying one buffer at a time to avoid cache contention.

Comment: Tnx for the link, really interesting. The point is that no matter how i define the interleaved RI buffer, vector of complex, vector of structures or other kind of variable i have three memory areas, two of them contains each only real or only imag and i have to copy them in interleaved form and i do not find any method apart using a for loop to accomplish the task .. try not use never a for loop and you will discover that simply tasks become combersome to carry out.  The fast way is to use memcpy since pointer increment is carried out in assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to construct an array of empty `complex` objects, but use `std::vector` and `emplace_back()` instead:

```
vector<complex<float>> cplxOut;

// to avoid reallocations when adding new elements
cplxOut.reserve(size); 

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    // create in-place complex number
    cplxOut.emplace_back(reals[i], imags[i]);
}
```